# Как свернуть программу (перехват кнопки HOME)

Tags: android, kotlin

Нужно программно по кнопке нажать кнопку HOME, но код показывает ошибку. Функция нажатия кнопки (setOnClickListener) содержится в MainActivity.kt и вызывает функцию из файла MyFuncs.kt  - Activity.exitSid() . Это интересно тем, что пользователь закрывает приложение, но данные из форм полей не пропадают, не стираются. По сути надо поставить приложение в состояние onPause().
Структура приложения: activity_main.xml >> content_main.xml >> fragment_first.xml >> fragment_second.xml. Кнопка нажатия содержится в activity_main и видна на всех фрагментах

```
doItRunExit?.setOnClickListener {
        this.exitSid()
    }
```

---->

```
fun Activity.exitSid() {
    val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
    i.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
    ContextCompat.startActivity(i)
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

просто 1 команда

```
this.moveTaskToBack(true)
```

Comment: работает, спасибо! столько разных вариантов в сети, этот тоже встречал, но мне казалось что этот метод устарел.

Comment: мне ещё нужно программно нажимать кнопку [HOME], а вы подсказали про [BACK]

Comment: @jurvrn может наоборот?) это кнопка Home. а кнопка Back просто onBackPressed();

Comment: при срабатывании this.moveTaskToBack(true) введенные данные в текстовый поля стираются при возврате программы, а при нажатии HOME - нет. Мне надо чтобы не стирались

Comment: @jurvrn this.moveTaskToBack(true) не должна стирать данные из полей. это и есть "эмуляция кнопки HOME". только что проверил на своем приложении. покажите ваш код, где вы используете moveTaskToBack, возможно так ошибки.

Comment: выложил  активити и файл с функциями на **github** https://github.com/intersk/test1.   Функция выхода запускается в 44 и 71 строке

Comment: @jurvrn так там же this.exitSid() а не this.moveTaskToBack(true)

Comment: this.exitSid()  вызывает  this.moveTaskToBack(true) во втором файле. Типа защита от случайного выхода чтобы не пришлось пользователю заново вносить данные. Но moveTaskToBack(true) это разве HOME ? после moveTaskToBack(true) запуск какой-то долгий, не такой как после нажатия HOME (экран постепенно прорисовывается)

Comment: @jurvrn сделал вашу extension-функцию в своем проекте. все работает как часы. поле не очищаются, остаюсь в том же фрагменте, где и был. на какой устройстве вы проверяете? возможно оно устарело.

Comment: спасибо за такое внимание, вот две съемки экрана с выходом по функции и через  кнопку home. Замедление и затенение экрана при запуске видно при выходе через функцию. https://radikal.ru/video/64yMnrEuAUZ и https://radikal.ru/video/rvJnT6DFCtD

Comment: @jurvrn тут ничего вам не подскажу, извините.

Comment: хорошо, я подозреваю что это "след" от Alert. Можно закрыть алерт программно перед выходом?